# Make me a fake loader

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Make a fake loader just like this :
[image]

### Parameters :

- Display `loading` (space) one of these cyclically`-\|/` (space) (percentage counter from 0-100) then a `%`.
- The percentage counter is supposed to increment by 1 every time the display changes.
- The time taken by counter to jump to next iteration is random. Any kind of random will do as long as the function/method is capable of generating all random integers having probability > 0 in range `1<= ms <=750` here `ms` being time in milliseconds.
- **Start** at `loading - 0 %`.
- **End** at `loading - 100 %`.
- NO INPUT is required.
- submit a **full** program or **function** or whatever similar.

The code that I used :

### C++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char a[15],b[]="-\\|/";
    int i=0,j=0,ms;
    while(j<101)
    {
        (i<3)?i++:i=0;
        wsprintf(a,"loading %c %d ",b[i],j++);
        printf(a);puts("%");
            //This part is to make the output look cool
        switch(rand()%9)
        {
            case 0:ms=1;break;
            case 1:ms=2;break;
            case 2:ms=5;break;
            case 3:ms=10;break;
            case 4:ms=15;break;
            case 5:ms=20;break;
            case 6:ms=25;break;
            case 7:ms=50;break;
            case 8:ms=500;
        }
        Sleep(ms);  //Otherwise this is supposed to be random
        if(j<101)   //like this Sleep(rand()%750+1);
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

### Winner

- the code with least bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101289/31716)

Comment: I didn't think this was a duplicate. This question cannot be implemented in ><>, but can be in *><> for example. I quite liked it.

Comment: @Mego The question isn't a duplicate. The output is a little different, the runtime is **completelly** different and the output **requires** a random time instead of a fixed 250ms delay. Answers on one question can't be used on the other without heavy modification. Please, read the questions.

Comment: As the author of the other challenge I'll step in with the dupe debate. Although the cycling chars (`\|/-`) are the same, the answer seems to be different in that it is not infinite and involves generation of random numbers, rather than a static output. Therefore I'll say, although I initially felt copied, this doesn't look like a dupe to me.

Comment: @flp.tkc this idea came from many places combined like I saw `-\|/` in some games.And I was inspired from console installation programs.

Comment: Are 1..750ms an exact, a maximal or a minimal range of numbers that we should generate for the delay?

Comment: @Titus If you know c-related languages then this should clarify your doubt `rand ()%750+1`.

Comment: My issue is that in PHP `rand()` returns an integer; and you cannot delay by milliseconds: it´s either seconds or microseconds. So: would [1..750k] microseconds be ok? or [1..1mill] microseconds?

Comment: @Titus Sure that's ok `[1,750K]` is acceptable. And a v.important point has been clarified i.e. the time-delay is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 45 bytes

```
101:"'loading'O'-\|/'@)O@qVO37&hD750Yr100/&Xx
```

Example run in the offline compiler:

[image]

Or try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=101%3A%22%27loading%27O%27-%5C%7C%2F%27%40%29O%40qVO37%26hD750Yr100%2F%26Xx&inputs=&version=19.6.0)

#### Explanation

```
101:          % Push array [1 2 ... 101]
"             % For each
  'loading'   %   Push this string
  O           %   Push 0. When converted to char it will be displayed as a space
  '-\|/'      %   Push this sring
  @)          %   Modular index into this string with iteration index
  O           %   Push 0
  @q          %   Iteration index minus 1
  V           %   Convert to string
  O           %   Push 0
  37          %   Push 37, which is ASCII for '%'
  &h          %   Concatenate horizontally into a string, Numbers are converted to char
  D           %   Display
  750Yr       %   Random integer with uniform distribution on [1 2 ... 750]
  100/        %   Divide by 100
  &Xx         %   Pause that many tenths of a second and clear screen
              % End (implicit)
```

Answer (score 16):

### Powershell, <s>71</s> <s>68</s> 65 Bytes

Similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101357/59735

Saved 3 bytes by not being an idiot (left the ... on loading)

-3 thanks to VisualMelon

changed 750 -> 751 to make sure 750 is included.

```
0..100|%{cls;"loading $("|/-\"[$_%4]) $_ %";sleep -m(random 751)}
```

Explanation:

```
0..100|%{                                  #For range 0-100...
    cls                                    #Clear Display
    "loading $("|/-\"[$_%4]) $_ %"    #Display the current string
    sleep -m(random 750)                  #Sleep random ms up to 750
}
```

Updated gif

[image]

Comment: your output is not _exactly_ same please see my gif and correct yours

Comment: I think you can drop the space after `-m`, and lose the parentheses around `$_%4` (seems to work on my box at least).

Comment: @VisualMelon thanks, the `()` were leftover from the other challenge I straight copied my code from.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>119</s> <s>113</s> 112 Bytes

I had originally gone with the random amount being `random()/.75`, however the endpoint wouldn't be included. There isn't much difference from this to the other question for the infinite load time except for the randomness and the fact that it actually ends.

```py
import time,random as r
for i in range(101):print'\rLoading','-\|/'[i%4],i,'%',;time.sleep(r.randint(1,750)/1e3)
```

<sup>*thanks to Jonathan Allan for saving 6 bytes, and DJMcMayhem for saving a byte!*</sup>

Comment: Save 6 bytes with `import time,random as r` and `r.randint`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Didn't realize you could import like that, thanks!

Comment: A for loop is slightly shorter: `for i in range(101):print'\rLoading','-\|/'[i%4],i,'%',;time.sleep(r.randint(1,750)/1e3)`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Whoops, I had been testing it with `range(1,101)` for some reason..

Comment: Acttually, I found something another 3 bytes shorter: `i=0;for c in'-\|/'*25:print'\rLoading',c,i,'%',;time.sleep(r.randint(1,750)/1e3);i+=1`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ooh, fancy ;) Thanks!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem although that will end at `99%` :(

Comment: @JonathanAllan Didn't think of that, I reverted my answer.

Comment: @Kade Looking at the rules you don't have to include 750 as a possible sleeping value as the comments under the question (and the sample code) say that it doesn't have to be uniform. So `random()/.7` should be valid and shorter.

Comment: @matsjoyce The example code has the 'cool bonus' in it, in the comments it does clearly state the normally used code which implies a value `1 <= x <= 750` to be generated. Also, dividing by a decimal will produce a sleep value over rather than under it. Even then, it isn't as simple because if `random()` decides to be `0.00005` I am now attempting to call sleep for under a millisecond, which isn't valid.

Comment: Incidentally, at this point in golfing, `import time,random as r` and `r.randint` don't save you any bytes from just using `import time,random` and `random.randint`.

Comment: The last comma in `print'\rLoading','-\|/'[i%4],i,'%',` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rainbolt [that doesn't seem to be the case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGYAb.png)

Answer (score 6):

### [*><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish) (Starfish), <s>86</s> 82 bytes

```
| v1*aoooooooo"loading K"&0"-\|/"
!0x1! +
%$<.0+af{od;?)*aa&:&Soono$&+1:&"  %"{o:}
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=D4AgbgjAVAhg9gxCBEAbOMAmBLAdgcxAGlkAyABmQFoAdYAemQCgBCcgDwhZAGomBSACQAeAHTkeMAGYBvOJgDcAfgCUsGKQBcpAMoJccQaR4RtyECH7I5mgL5A)

<s>This may be able to be golfed more, but I don't see anything super obvious. It sleeps 100ms, 400ms, or 700ms, if this isn't random enough, let me know!</s>

Thanks to @TealPelican for saving me 4 bytes and making it much more random!

The biggest challenges I found (while still trying to keep it small) were randomness, and actually outputting "loading - 100 %" at the end, instead of just exiting at my nearest convenience :p.

Comment: Hey, I love this take on the ><> language, it opens up a lot more challenges :D - I've had a bit of a tweak on your code and I've not reduced it by much but changed the random numbers. [Link to ><> code](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/wAWkrBoMNiZvGaH9y) The only change to make this viable in *><> would be changing the ~ from the code link to S to use the time. This does generate random numbers all the way up to 749 and cuts out some excess stack operations. P.S I'd love it if you could make *><> online interpreter :D

Comment: @Tealpelican, thanks! I love your changes, especially the random number generator! I'd also love an online *><> interpreter :p. I don't play around with JS too often, but I'll both look into playing with JS, or maybe running the Go interpreter through GopherJS first for a head-start. :)

Comment: Thanks, it took a while to actually come up with a working version but this seems the mosted golfed I could generate. I'll keep my eye out for it and if not may dabble into making a python one. I still think the first line could be golfed a bit more but I haven't been able to do it myself.

Comment: @Tealpelican hopefully this fills the online interpreter itch, or at least gets the ball rolling. I'm going to look into a way to share code later. https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: That was quick, just running the program in it now and seems to work fine :D I'm going to try have a look at using this for some challenges this week.

Comment: @Tealpelican awesome I look forward to that! I just added a share feature, which I hope is okay (just does text compression).

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 185 bytes

```
@set s=-\!/
@for /l %%i in (0,1,100)do @call:l %%i
@exit/b
:l
@cls
@set c=%s:~0,1%
@set s=%s:~1%%c%
@echo Loading %c:!=^|% %1 %%
@set/aw=%random%%%751
@ping>nul 1.1 -n 1 -w %w%
```

The timing is fairly poor unfortunately, but Batch doesn't have anything better to use than `ping`.

Comment: This only works on Windows.  FreeCom DOS batch gives ````Loading   %
Invalid switch. - /aw  ````  (I would love to try it in MS DOS if I can still find my copy).

Comment: @BrianMinton: Good luck running it on MS DOS (no ping command)

Comment: @BrianMinton It requires CMD.EXE because of the advanced variable substitutions.

Comment: @Joshua Well, not built in at least; that didn't happen until Windows 2000.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 67 bytes

```perl6
for |<- \ | />xx* Z 0..100 {print "\rloading $_ %";sleep .750.rand}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
for

  # produce a list of all the pairs of values

  |<- \ | /> xx *   # a flat infinite list of "clock faces"
  Z                 # zipped with
  0 .. 100          # all the numbers from 0 to 100 inclusive

  # &zip / &infix:<Z> stop on the shortest list

{

  # ｢$_｣ will look something like ｢("/", 39)｣
  # when it is coerced to a Str, all of its elements
  # will be coerced to Str, and joined with spaces

  print "\rloading $_ %";

  sleep .750.rand

}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>128</s> <s>118</s> <s>116</s> <s>115</s> <s>112</s> <s>110</s> 109 bytes

This seems to work perfectly fine, even with this sketchy source of "random" numbers.

```js
(X=_=>setTimeout(i>99||X,1+new Date%750,document.body.innerHTML=`<pre>Loading ${'-\\|/'[i%4]} ${i++}%`))(i=0)
```

---

**Alternative 1**, Javascript + HTML, 16 + 84 bytes

This one uses an already-existing element to display the remaining content:

```js
(X=_=>setTimeout(i>99||X,1+new Date%750,a.innerHTML=`${'-\\|/'[i%4]} ${i++}%`))(i=0)
```

```html
Loading <a id=a>
```

**Alternative 2**, 95 bytes

If I can assume a tab is opened and that you're pasting this into the console:

```
(X=_=>setTimeout(i>99||X,1+new Date%750,document.title=`Loading ${'-\\|/'[i%4]} ${i++}%`))(i=0)
```

Instead of showing the HTML, the title of the document will change.

---

Thank you to [@user2428118](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13486/user2428118) for saving 2 bytes!

Comment: You can drop the `()` after `Date` to save two bytes.

Comment: @user2428118 I didn't knew that that works! Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

## F#, 118 bytes

```
async{let r=System.Random()
for i in 0..100 do printf"\rLoading %O %d %%""|/-\\".[i%4]i;do!Async.Sleep(r.Next(1,750))}
```

In order to run this snippet, pass it into `Async.Start` or `Async.RunSynchronously`.

Comment: Instant upvote because of F#

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>90</s> <s>83</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> Bytes

**77:**

The closing `;` is not needed.

```
for(;$i<101;usleep(rand(1,75e4)))echo"\rloading ",'-\|/'[$i%4],' ',$i+++0,'%'
```

78:

While looking for another workaround to get a 0 initially without initializing the variable I came up with this:

```
for(;$i<101;usleep(rand(1,75e4)))echo"\rloading ",'-\|/'[$i%4],' ',$i+++0,'%';
```

Changed back to echo to win a few bytes as I only used printf to force-format as int. By incrementing the incremented $i with 0 I get a valid integer. By using single quotes as string delimiter the backslash does not need to be escaped, resulting in another byte freed

80:

Moving the increment of $i from the last for-section to the prinf gave me another 3 off. (See comments below)

```
for(;$i<101;usleep(rand(1,75e4)))printf("\rloading %s %d%%","-\\|/"[$i%4],$i++);
```

83:

Removed init of a variable with the loaderstates.

```
for(;$i<101;usleep(rand(1,75e4)),$i++)printf("\rloading %s %d%%","-\\|/"[$i%4],$i);
```

90:

I tried removing the init of $i to gain some bytes, as I had to add quite a few to enable the loader animation. printf adds 2 as opposed to echo, but formatting NULL as an integer results in 0.

```
for($l='-\|/';$i<101;usleep(rand(0,750)*1e3),$i++)printf("\rloading %s %d%%",$l[$i%4],$i);
```

Comment: There's one mistake: The question requires the delay to be between 1 and 750, inclusive. You have between 0 and 750. Also, you could move the increment to the `printf`, saving you a single byte: `for(;$i<101;usleep(rand(1,750)*1e3))printf("\rloading %s %d%%",'-\|/'[$i%4],$i++);` (82 bytes)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel rand() is [inclusive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), or is this because of the multiplication by *1e3?  I'm going to sneak in that free byte.

Comment: The question **requires** a random interval between 1ms and 750ms (inclusive). `rand(0,750)*1e3` returns a value between 0 (invalid) and 750, which is multiplied by 1000. `rand(1,75e4)` returns a value between 1 (invalid) and 750000. The delay must be `rand(1,750)*1e3`, since you use `usleep()`. It works with *microseconds*, which is 1000x smaller than a millisecond.

Comment: This may take you inconveniently close to user59178´s answer, but `echo` is 3 bytes shorter than `printf`. You may want to put the most recent version to the top and use `#title` instead of `**title**`. And there is a space missing between the number and the `%`.

Comment: @Titus I can't use echo here because I didn't initialize my $i, null to string evaluates to '', via printf I force integer (%d) resulting in null = 0. #justphpthings

Comment: So you would start with `0 %` ... or not? But nm; this adds a little diversity to the answers.

Comment: With a regular error it would start with %, not even a number in front of it. I thought I would be able to make it shorter than the current shortest PHP answer because I didn't have to init ($i=-1 is 5 chars, whilst printf is only 2 longer than echo) but I guess the needed placeholders made it longer again. This does give me an idea to possibly golf it even further

Comment: If you run with `-r`, you have to use double quotes and you need the final `;` (+1 byte). If not, you have to surround the code with PHP tags (+4 bytes). Nice one none the less.

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, <s>113</s> 87 bytes

***-36 bytes thanks to lealand***

```
{p=-1;101.times{print"\rLoading ${"-\\|/"[p++%4]} $p%";sleep Math.random()*750as int}}​
```

Comment: 84 bytes, and should run from Groovy console: `p=-1;101.times{println"Loading ${"-\\|/"[p++%4]} $p%";sleep Math.random()*750as int}`

Comment: Although the question owner not explicitly requested, he probably wants the consecutive loading messages to overwrite each other. There is no size difference, so better change `println"Loading…` → `print"\rLoading…`. And remove that variable p, use the implicit it instead.

Answer (score 3):

**C#, <strike>170</strike> <strike>149</strike> 135 Bytes**

```
()=>{for(int i=0;i++<=100;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1,750)))Console.Write($"\rloading {@"-\|/"[i % 4]} {i} %");};
```

Ungolfed:

```
static void l()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1, 750)))
        Console.Write($"\rloading {@"-\|/"[i % 4]} {i} %");   
}
```

<strike>I won't guarantee that every character in this is right, please correct me if there are compilation errors. I had to type the whole thing on my phone so I might have accidentally included some errors...  ¯_(ツ)_/¯
I hope you guys forgive me that</strike>

Tested it on my PC, works like a charm and I even saved a whole 20 bytes thanks to pmbanka :)

Comment: You can use `\r` (carriage return) instead of `Console.Clear()`. You can also inline s variable to save some bytes.

Comment: You can also save an extra byte by replacing the `i<=100` for `i<101`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)` can be rewritten as `for (int i =  0; i++ <= 100;)` Then you can put the Thread.Sleep within the place where i++ was and save both curly brackets. Cutting 3 bytes in total

Comment: Also OP didnt ask for a Programm so you can replace `static void l()` with `()=>`

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>162</s> 104 bytes

Modification of [Zachary's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101310) on a related question, with massive improvements by manatwork:

```
s='-\|/'
for x in {0..100};{
printf "\rloading ${s:x%4:1} $x %%"
sleep `printf .%03d $[RANDOM%750+1]`
}
```

I had to look up how to do [random numbers](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) in bash.

### Ungolfed / Explained

```
s='-\|/'
for x in {0..100}
{
    # \r returns the carriage to the beginning of the current line.
    # ${s:x%4:1} grabs a substring from s, at index x%4, with a length of 1.
    printf "\rloading ${s:x%4:1} $x %%"

    # "$RANDOM is an internal bash function that returns
    #   a pseudorandom integer in the range 0 - 32767."
    # .%03d is a dot followed by a base-ten number formatted to 3 places,
    #   padded with zeros if needed.
    # sleep accepts a floating point number to represent milliseconds.
    sleep `printf .%03d $[RANDOM%750+1]`
}
```

Comment: Nice first try. See [Tips for golfing in Bash](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash) for improvement tips. Personally would go with `s='-\|/';for x in {0..100};{ printf "\rloading ${s:x%4:1} $x %%";sleep \`printf .%03d $[RANDOM%750+1]\`; }` BTW, our fellow site [unix.se] also has a question about [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks).

Comment: @manatwork Good links!  I didn't know about `$[math]`, using `{ }` instead of `do done`, or using back ticks instead of `$()`.  Yeah, reusing $x for accessing the loader graphic array makes sense.  Also, slapping a `.` in front of the number to get the decimal for sleep is pretty sweet!

Answer (score 2):

## C <s>112</s> 103 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to @G. Sliepen.  Not very exciting, just a golf of your C++ answer basically.  Also not a very exciting random function.  I thought about `Sleep(c[i%4])`, or `Sleep(i)` but they're not random at all!

```
#import<windows.h>
i;f(){for(;i<101;printf("\rloading %c %d %%","-\\|/"[i%4],i++),Sleep(rand()%750+1));}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <windows.h>
int i;
void f() {
  for(;i<101;) {
    printf("\rloading %c %d %%", "-\\|/"[i%4], i++);
    Sleep(rand()%750+1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid but `rand ()%750` generates numbers from 0-749 you will need to add 1.

Comment: Changing `rand()%750` to `rand()%751` won't give the result you want. It will generate a random value between **0** and 750. In the question, the delay **must** be between **1** and 750 (inclusive). According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm, the `rand()` function generates numbers between 0 and (at least) 32767. If you do `0 % 750`, you get 0 since `0 / <anything> == 0`.

Comment: Shave off 9 bytes by removing `char*c="-\\|/";` and using the literal string directly instead of the variable `c`: `printf(...,"-\\|/"[i%4],...)`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>66</s> 79 bytes

```
for($i=-1;++$i<101;usleep(rand(1,75e4)))echo"\rloading ","-\\|/"[$i%4]," $i %";
```

Unfortunately I had to assign $i in order to get it to print '0'.
Use like:

```
php -r 'for($i=-1;++$i<101;usleep(rand(1,75e4)))echo"\rloading ","-\\|/"[$i%4]," $i %";'
```

Edits: thanks to Titus confirming exactly what's allowed with Mukul Kumar we can save 3 bytes with a less restricted range, but not all 9 bytes with an unrestricted range. Thanks also for pointing out that I forgot the cycling character and providing a simple solution to do it.

Comment: The random requirements are that you generate all 1ms to 750ms with a possibility>0. I can´t  see that other values are prohibited. `rand(1,75e4)` saves 3 bytes; `1e6` can save another one; and no parameters at all save 9 bytes altogether; and I don´t see that violate any rule. But you forgot to cycle the character: +16 for `","-\\|/"[$i%4],"` instead of `-`.

Comment: @Titus Won't `usleep(rand(1,75e4))` generate a random interval between 1 **microsecond** and 750 **milliseconds**? Also, according to the question, the interval must be between 1 and 750, inclusive.

Comment: See the latest comments on the question: `1 to 75e4` is acceptable.

Comment: @Titus I'd considered changes like those but decided to go with what seemed implied by the question (integer millisecond delays). Thanks for asking exactly what was allowed!

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 133 Bytes

```
Dynamic[If[x<100,x++,,x=0];Row@{"Loading ",StringPart["-\|/",1+x~Mod~4]," ",x,"%"},
    UpdateInterval:>RandomReal@.75,TrackedSymbols:>{}]
```

This will run once, assuming x is undefined.  `Clear@x` will restart it.

55 characters tied up in verbosity :/

Comment: Is that a fixed interval or will it be repeatedly randomized?

Comment: It's randomized.  UpdateInterval:>.75 would have been fixed

Comment: @Titus: I believe `UpdateInterval:>RandomReal@.75` repeatedly calls `RandomReal`, but `UpdateInterval->RandomReal@.75` would call it only once.

Answer (score 2):

### R - 94 bytes

```
for(i in 0:100){cat('\rLoading',c('-','\\','|','/')[i%%4+1],i,'%');Sys.sleep(sample(750,1)/1e3)}
```

Really nice that `sample(750,1) == sample(1:750,1)`.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML + JS (ES6), 16 + 87 = 103 bytes

```js
(f=_=>a.innerHTML='\\|/-'[i++%4]+` ${i<100&&setTimeout(f,Math.random()*750),i} %`)(i=0)
```

```html
loading <a id=a>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), noncompeting 40 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

Just going back through old challenges (as in challenges that were made before *Noodel*) and competing with *Noodel* to find where it is weak.

```
Loading¤”ḋḟƇḣ⁺s¤ṡ⁺Ḷ101ạ¤%ɱṠĖ²⁺Çṛ749⁺1ḍ€Ḃ
```

If final output does not matter, then can save 2 bytes.

```
Loading¤”ḋḟƇḣ⁺s¤ṡ⁺Ḷ101ạ¤%ɱṠĖ²⁺Çṛ749⁺1ḍ
```

*Noodel* pushes the top of the stack to the screen at the end of the program so by adding the `€Ḃ` it prevents that from happening.

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=Loading%C2%A4%E2%80%9D%E1%B8%8B%E1%B8%9F%C6%87%E1%B8%A3%E2%81%BAs%C2%A4%E1%B9%A1%E2%81%BA%E1%B8%B6101%E1%BA%A1%C2%A4%25%C9%B1%E1%B9%A0%C4%96%C2%B2%E2%81%BA%C3%87%E1%B9%9B749%E2%81%BA1%E1%B8%8D%E2%82%AC%E1%B8%82&input=&run=true)

#### How It Works

```
Loading¤”ḋḟƇḣ⁺s¤ṡ⁺Ḷ101ạ¤%ɱṠĖ²⁺Çṛ749⁺1ḍ€Ḃ # Main Noodel script.

Loading¤”ḋḟƇḣ⁺s¤ṡ⁺                       # Creates the array ["Loading¤-¤", "Loading¤\¤", "Loading¤|¤", "Loading¤/¤"]
Loading¤                                 # Pushes the string "Loading¤"
        ”Ƈḟḋḣ                            # Pushes the array ["-", "\", "|", "/"]
             ⁺s                          # Concats "Loading¤" to each element in the array by prepending.
               ¤                         # Pushes a "¤" onto the stack.
                ṡ                        # Pushes
                 ⁺

                  Ḷ101ạ¤%ɱṠĖ²⁺Çṛ749⁺1ḍ   # Main loop that creates the animation.
                  Ḷ101                   # Loop the following code 101 times.
                      ạ                  # Pushes on a copy of the next animation element from the array.
                       ¤%                # Pushes the string "¤%"
                         ɱ               # Pushes on the current count of the number of times that have looped (zero based).
                          Ṡ              # Swaps the two items at the bottom of the stack.
                           Ė             # Pushes the item at the bottom of the stack to the top (which will be the string selected from the array).
                            ²⁺           # Concat twice appending the loop count then the string "¤%" to the string selected from the array.
                              Ç          # Pops the string off of the stack, clears the screen, then prints the string.
                               ṛ749      # Randomly generate an integer from 0 to 749.
                                   ⁺1    # Increment the random number producing a random number from 1 - 750.
                                     ḍ   # Pop off the stack and delay for that number of milliseconds.

                                      €Ḃ # Ends the loop and prevents anything else being displayed.
                                      €  # Ends the loop (new line could be used as well)
                                       Ḃ # Destroys the current stack therein, nothing gets pushed to the screen at the end of the program.
```

```html
<div id="noodel" code="Loading¤”ḋḟƇḣ⁺s¤ṡ⁺Ḷ101ạ¤%ɱṠĖ²⁺Çṛ749⁺1ḍ€Ḃ" input="" cols="14" rows="2"></div>

<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/noodel-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are there so many `¤`s?

Comment: @KritixiLithos _Noodel_ uses spaces as a NOP so for printing a space the `¤` is used:)

Comment: Btw, it's nice that there is a stack snippet for this :)

Comment: How does the snippet work? Does the imported script find the element with the id of `noodle`, then translate the `code` to Javascript?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Yes. The "parser" is the _JavaScript_ function `noodel` which handles the `code` properly. It translates the `code` into tokens that are _JavaScript_ objects that get chained together then executed. The `ppcg.min.js` creates the proper _HTML_ objects and translates the output of what is parsed into the _HTML_ objects to create the display. Every token is executed by stepping through them triggering a step event which is registered to update the screen:) Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

### C <s>126</s> 121 bytes

```
f(){i=0;char c[]="/-\\|";for(;i<101;i++){printf("\rloading %c %d %% ",c[i%4],i);fflush(stdout);usleep(1000*(rand()%75));}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
 void f()
 {
  int i=0;
  char c[]="/-\\|";
  for(;i<101;i++)
  {
    printf("\rloading %c %d %% ",c[i%4], i);
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(1000*(rand()%75));  
  }
 }
```

@Carcigenicate @ Mukul Kumar Did not read between the lines there, Thanks! :)

Comment: c[] is not random... But is cycling....

Comment: Or, in other words, you're not supposed to pick a random character from "\|/-", you're supposed to display /, then -, then \, then |, in a cycle.

Comment: @MukulKumar @ Carcigenicate  Updated the code so that it does what the spec says regarding cycling characters!

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>122</s> <s>120</s> <s>119</s> 108 bytes

I misread the challenge and created an infinite loader that restarted at 0 once it passed 100. Making it into a one time only loader:

```
a='\|/-';for i=0:100;clc;disp(['Loading ',a(1),' ',num2str(i),' %']);a=a([2:4,1]);pause(0.749*rand+.001);end
```

Circulating `a`, `a=a([2:4,1])` was flawr's idea [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101293/31516). Also, saved 2 bytes by skipping the parentheses after `rand` thanks to MattWH.

Comment: Should it be `.749*rand()+.001`? This can wait for 751ms. Also you can leave the `()` off rand and save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## **MATLAB, 108 bytes**

```
function k;for i=0:100;a='-\|/';pause(rand*.749+.001);clc;['loading ' a(mod(i,3)+1) ' ' num2str(i) ' %']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 110 bytes

```
(for((i 101))(printf"Loading ~a ~a % ~n"(list-ref'("-" "\\" "|" "/")(modulo i 4))i)(sleep(/(random 750)1000)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f)
  (for ((i 101))
    (printf "Loading ~a ~a % ~n" (list-ref '("-" "\\" "|" "/") (modulo i 4)) i)
    (sleep (/(random 750)1000))))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output: 
[image]

(This gif file is showing slower display than actual)

Comment: What's with the stuff at the end in the gif?

Comment: This seem to be an artefact from screen capture program.

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang, 250 bytes

Noncompeting, requires language features which postdate the question

```
def D def
D w io.write
D l e+"loading"+s
D z string.char 8
D s string.char 32
D d datetime.wait 750.mult random.rand()
D e z.repeat 24
D n set i 1+i
D k s+n+s+"%"
set i -1
label 1
w l+"-"+k
if i=100
exit()
d
w l+"\"+k
d
w l+"|"+k
d
w l+"/"+k
d
goto 1
```

I should probably fix some bugs related to string literal parsing soon.

Answer (score 1):

## <strike>107</strike> 75 Ruby

*-32 thanks to manatwork*

**Normal**

```rb
i=0
(0..100).each{|c|
system'clear'
puts"loading #{'\|/-'[i=-~i%4]} #{c} %"
sleep rand*(0.750-0.01)+0.01
}
```

**Golfed**

```rb
101.times{|c|$><<"\rloading #{'-\|/'[c%4]} #{c} %";sleep rand*0.749+0.001}
```

Comment: Given you have a single line of output to overwrite, the `system'clear'` is overkill here. Also the use of the separate variable i. Oh, and precalculate where possible: `0.750-0.01` → `0.749` (also note that you lack one decimal place in 0.01 – should be 0.001). The resulting `101.times{|c|$><<"\rloading #{'-\|/'[c%4]} #{c} %";sleep rand*0.749+0.001}` becomes very similar to [Conor O'Brien](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957)'s [Ruby answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101321) in [Loading… Forever](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101289) but so is the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 3, 149 bytes

```
import time,random;f=0;n=0
while n<=100:
 print("Loading...","|/-\\"[f],n,"%",end="\r");f+=1
 if f>=3:f=0
 n+=1
 time.sleep(random.uniform(.25,.75))
```

Similar to Loading... Forever, but I did have to edit my answer from there a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 116

```
set i 0;time {lmap c {- \\ | /} {puts -nonewline stderr "\rloading $c $i%";after [expr int(187*rand())]};incr i} 100
```

Playable in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOXoybnVSOVJEU00

Comment: Your output seems little off...

Comment: hmm,,, my code disappeared! ...

Comment: I mean that your output is in this format "loading... xx%" instead it should be like this "loading - xx%" where '-' varies as explained in the question.

Comment: @MukulKumar: Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 80 bytes

```
For(I,0,100
For(A,0,randE2
End
Text(0,0,"loading "+sub("-\|/",1+fPart(I/4),1)+" ",I," %
End
```

The randomness comes from the `For(` loop (E is scientific E token) and since TI-Basic is interpreted there is also automatically some overhead. Remember that in TI-Basic, lowercase letters and some less common ASCII symbols are two bytes each (so specifically for this program, `l o a d i n g sub( \ | %` are the two-byte tokens

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 109 bytes

```clj
(doseq[[c i](map vector(cycle"\\|/-")(range 101))](print"\rloading"c i\%)(flush)(Thread/sleep(rand-int 751)))
```

Loops over a list of the range of numbers from 0 to 100, zipped with an infinite list of `"\|/-"` repeating forever.

```clj
; (map vector...) is how you zip in Clojure
;  All arguments after the first to map are lists. The function is expected to
;  take as many arguments as there are lists. vector is var-arg.
(doseq [[c i] (map vector (cycle "\\|/-") (range 101))]
  ; \r to erase the old line
  (println "\rloading" c i \%)
  (Thread/sleep (rand-int 751)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Visual Basic, 371 Bytes

```
module m
sub main()
Dim s as Object
for i as Integer=0 to 100
Select Case new System.Random().next(0,9)
Case 0
s=1
Case 1
s=2
Case 2
s=5
Case 3
s=10
Case 4
s=15
Case 5
s=20
Case 6
s=25
Case 7
s=50
Case 8
s=500
End Select
Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)
console.write("loading "+"-\|/"(i mod 4)+" "+i.tostring+" %")
system.threading.thread.sleep(s)
next
end sub
end module
```

## Expanded:

```
module m
    sub main()
        Dim s as Object
        for i as Integer=0 to 100
            Select Case new System.Random().next(0,9)
                Case 0
                s=1
                Case 1
                s=2
                Case 2
                s=5
                Case 3
                s=10
                Case 4
                s=15
                Case 5
                s=20
                Case 6
                s=25
                Case 7
                s=50
                Case 8
                s=500
            End Select
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)
            console.write("loading " + "-\|/"(i mod 4) + " " + i.tostring + " %")
            system.threading.thread.sleep(s)
        next
    end sub
end module
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 130 bytes

```java
()->{for(int n=0;n<101;Thread.sleep((long)(1+Math.random()*750)))System.out.print("\rloading "+"-\\|/".charAt(n%4)+" "+n+++" %");}
```

**Explanation:**

```java
()->{                           // Method without parameter nor return-type
  for(int n=0;n<101;            //  Loop from 0 to 100
      Thread.sleep((long)(1+Math.random()*750)))
                                //   And sleep randomly 1-750 ms 
    System.out.print(           //   Print:
      "\r                       //    Reset to the start of the line
      loading "                 //    Literal "loading "
      +"-\\|/".charAt(n%4)+" "  //    + the spinner char & a space
      +n++                      //    + the number (and increase it by 1)
      +" %");                   //    + a space & '%'
                                //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
}                               // End of method
```

**Output gif:**

[image]